# Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined when using npm to install a external module for nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, backend, web-development-server

I am using module npm install superheroes to install the external superheroes nodejs module. But every time its' giving me [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGDJp.png):

[image]

Comment: Can you show the node version you're running in?

Comment: Did you look at the complete log as suggested by the output?

Comment: The  node version is v12.18.3

Comment: My problem is resolved. Instead on installing v.12.18.3 install version https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.15.3/node-v10.15.3-x64.msi